# Problemas ao pegar dados no registo anterior - MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho esta query que retorna o útimo registo e o anterior:

```
SELECT Colaborador 
FROM centrodb.Registolistagem 
LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.Registolistagem2 ON centrodb.Registolistagem2.IdLista = centrodb.Registolistagem.Id
WHERE Carro = 'G3 Ala B' 
ORDER BY centrodb.Registolistagem.Id DESC LIMIT 2
```

Mas agora pretendia pegar só no registo anterior ao último, como o posso fazer?

Comment: Tente colocar o `LIMIT 1,1` no lugar de `LIMIT 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `LIMIT` funciona da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT * FROM [TABELA] ORDER BY [COLUNA] LIMIT [INDICE_INICIAL], [NÚMERO_ELEMENTOS]
```

Onde o `INDICE_INICIAL` é o elemento inicial a ser buscado - 1, ou seja, o índice dele, e o `NÚMERO_ELEMENTOS` é a quantidade de registros a serem buscadas após o índice inicial.

Para o seu caso, seria `LIMIT 1, 1`: Começando do *segundo* elemento (índice 1), traga UM registro.

Mais informações sobre isso você pode encontrar aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224951/return-the-nth-record-from-mysql-query